# progressbar window does not close

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

In my WPF C# project I've created a Window that has got a ProgressBar inside.
I use it when I need to do long calculation, so I show it until calculation ends.
It is an unlimited progress bar as you can see from XAML:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="Solvers_ProgressBar" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
 Height="30" Margin="36,53,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220" 
 Minimum="0" Maximum="100" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
```

It works in all situations but I have problem in a certain window.
I show the progress bar each time I change a dropdown but, sometimes, the progress bar is not closed and remains pending.

Here is the code of window class that has the progress bar:

```
public class SolverProgressBarWindowHandler
{

    private Thread StatusThread = null;

    public SolversProgressBarWindow Popup = null;

    public void Start()
    {
        //create the thread with its ThreadStart method
        this.StatusThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                this.Popup = new SolversProgressBarWindow();

                this.Popup.Closed += (lsender, le) =>
                {
                    //when the window closes, close the thread invoking the shutdown of the dispatcher            

                    this.Popup.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();                        
                    this.Popup = null;
                    this.StatusThread = null;
                };

                this.Popup.ShowDialog();
                //this call is needed so the thread remains open until the dispatcher is closed
                System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        });

        //run the thread in STA mode to make it work correctly
        this.StatusThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        this.StatusThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
        this.StatusThread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (this.Popup != null)
        {
            //need to use the dispatcher to call the Close method, because the window is created in another thread, and this method is called by the main thread
            this.Popup.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.Popup.Close();
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Debugging  the code, it seems that sometimes `Popup` is null, so Close method does not working.

EDIT: I've tried by adding a Thread.Sleep(2000) before the Stop method...and it works...so maybe if operations between Start and Stop are so quickly executed, the Thread is slower than the main process and Popup is not set up

Comment: Sure Start before Stop?

Comment: what does it mean? do I need to have Stop before Start method?

Comment: Popup is null till Start. If Popup is null when Close, I doubt that Start has been called. Easy to check.

Comment: @dytori yes easy to check...but why it does not work?

Comment: If you are sure Start is called every time before Stop is called, the problem stays elsewhere. You can make `Popup` a property, set a breakpoint on its `set`, and see how it goes. Still more rooms for debugging there, I guess.